# Error while installing APK without Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, apk, privacy

I've downloaded some app* from the play store via the bluestacks emulator and then copied the apk off the emulated system to my android phone. But when I want to install it, I'll get an error which correspodends to the code 'INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY'.

Note: On my phone (GT-I9195) I'm running CM without gapps.

My guess is that the app is using libraries which are provided by the gapps.

Does anybody know how to fix this or another way to install apps from the play store without gapps?

*https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hafas.android.db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible install apps of google play without gapps, but you can install a "minimal google play"

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1918484

Answer (score 0):

Install Google apps by going to apkmirror.com and searching google play store. Now download the newest version of this. Enable installation of apps by unknown sources in settings=>security. Now find the file you downloaded and install it. You should now have Google play store on your phone and can now download this app and others a lot easier.